# Need hints for completing code:

Tags: vba, listbox

This question has been answered.
Do not want to leave it exposed.

```
Private Sub btnTTL_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles findzipButton.Click

    Dim zipCode As String

    'forgot

    If (ListBox1.FindString(findzipButton.Text) >= 0) Then
        ttlTextBox.Text = "$15"
    ElseIf (ListBox2.FindString(findzipButton.Text) >= 0) Then
        ttlTextBox.Text = "$20"
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The zipcode was not found!")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I think your trying to do is match the input a user puts into a text box with a selection in the either ListBoxA or ListBoxB. I just tried this in VS 2012, and it seems to work in the way the problem above describes, but I'm only trying to find and display the shipping cost:

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ListBox1.Items.Add("60611")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("60234")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("56789")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("23467")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("60543")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("60561")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("55905")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("89567")


    ListBox2.Items.Add("50978")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("78432")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("98432")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("97654")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("20245")

End Sub

Private Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click

    Dim zipCode As String = txtZipCode.Text

    If (ListBox1.FindString(zipCode) >= 0) Then
        txtShipping.Text = "$15"
    ElseIf (ListBox2.FindString(zipCode) >= 0) Then
        txtShipping.Text = "$20"
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The zipcode was not found!")
    End If

End Sub
```

You were on the right track. What you needed to do was compare what the user actually input to the textbox to what was available in the Listbox. The FindItem() method will then result a Long. If it did find your search string it will build the shipping text box.

Comment: If you give me one moment I will get some screen shots on my DropBox so you can see if this is what you expect, or perhaps I misinterpreted the problem. Or I can put up the solution files.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.  Compare what the user actually input versus what is in list box 1.  If it isn't in there, it will check listbox 2.  If the number still isnt' found, then it would display not found.  I didn't learn about FindItem() method yet.  thank you so much